# jquery easyui data grid editor for combo box not loading with grails

Tags: grails, datagrid, combobox, editor, jquery-easyui

I am using Jquery Easyui Datagrid with grails this is my code for creating the grid in GSP file:-

```
<table class="easyui-datagrid"
         data-options="fit:true,idField:'id',pageNmber:1,pageList:[25,50,75,100]"              pagination="true" id="importGrid">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th data-options="field:'firstName',sortable:true,width:15,nowrap:true" >First Name</th>
        <th data-options="field:'lastName',sortable:true,width:25,nowrap:true" editor="{type:'validatebox',options:{required:true}}" >Last Name</th>
        <th data-options="field: 'firstNameLastName',sortable:true,width:130,nowrap:true" >First Name Last Name</th>
        <th data-options="field:'displayName',sortable:true,rowspan:2,width:80,nowrap:true">Display Name</th>
        <th data-options="field:'relocation',sortable:true,width:130,nowrap:true">Relocation</th>
        <th data-options="field:'proficiency',sortable:true,width:130,nowrap:true" editor="{
                type:'combobox',
                options:{
                    valueField:'rightid',
                    textField:'rightname',
                    data:aRights,
                    required:true
                }
            }">Proficiency</th>
        <th data-options="field:'subProficiency',sortable:true,width:130,nowrap:true" editor='proficiencyEditor'>Sub Proficiency</th>
        <th data-options="field:'uploadResume',sortable:true,width:130,nowrap:true,">Relocation</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

i tried using url which refers to one action in controller but it doesn't work.so to make it work with gsp now i am using a js variable which i have declared in the same gsp. I have the variable aRights like this:-

```
<script> var aRights =  [{rightid: 'V', rightname: 'View Only'},
                                {rightid: 'E', rightname: 'Edit FPC'},
                                {rightid: 'A',  rightname: 'Admin'},
                                {rightid: 'N', rightname: 'None'}
                ] ;
</script>
```

But editor is never visible..

this is the code i am using to populate the data grid.This code is in js:-

```
  $('#importGrid').datagrid({
    url:'/'+productName+'/TestList/excelImport',
             queryParams:{
        list: hiddenMapForFields,
        file:fileName            
    },
    pageNumber: 1,
   });
```

I am new to Jquery easyui editors.Please let me know where i am wrong and help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to reproduce your bug.

http://jsfiddle.net/niscio/63fyrzL8/1/

If you read the documentation the real problem for editing is that you have to use edatagrid declaration

```
 $('#ID').edatagrid({... options ...});
```

Comment: Thanks.Its working for me after making changes u mentioned above.